# virtual machine scaleset doesn't show up on agent pool

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent, virtual-machine-scale-set

Hope you are doing well,

I am testing the Azure DevOps environment, and I created a virtual machine scale-set to execute my build pipeline, but what is very odd is that I created the pool based on Microsoft instruction, but when I go to check the agent to see the instance, there is no instance appeared however when I check on azure portal | virtual machine scale set they are already there.

When I commit and run the pipeline, it gives me this error "The agent request is not running because all potential agents are running other requests. Current position in queue: 1

No agents in pool hostedself are currently able to service this request." do you have any idea what is the issue?

Thank you in advance,

Best Regards,

I have explained everything that I tried, I tried many times creating new pools new VMSS but didn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this doc: [Orchestration modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/scale-set-agents?view=azure-devops#orchestration-modes)

> Azure virtual machine scale sets can be configured with two orchestration modes: Uniform and Flexible. Azure Pipelines support for the Uniform orchestration mode is generally available, to all customers.

By default, Azure VMSS will use **Flexible** mode.

To solve this issue, you need to manually select the **Uniform** mode when creating the VMSS.

[image]

Upon creation **Uniform** orchestration mode VMSS in Azure Portal, check the related settings addressed in this link : [Create the scale set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/scale-set-agents?view=azure-devops#create-the-scale-set)

**Upgrade policy - Manual**

[image]

**Scaling - Manual scale**

[image]

Then you can create the VMSS Agent Pool in Azure DevOps and check if it can work.